# Struggling with a Java JDBC:sqlite connection using Intellij

Tags: java, sql, xml, database, fxml

My full project is on Github.com/DSkilton

I have tried dozens of ways to get this to work, I've read about classpaths, using Class.forName() and not using it, Xerials JDBC [instructions](https://github.cm/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) which suggests using / rather than escaping \ for the path String. I've read through some of Oracles suggestions, Stackoverflow and SQlites [tutorial](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/sqlite-jdbc-driver/) on how to set up. I've really *tried* to research this but am still coming up blank!

Inside my src folder are the following folders: controller, images, lib, model, sample and view.

In the controller folder is databaseConnect.java and in the lib folder is jdbc-api-1.4.jar.

In my databaseConnect file I have the following:

```
public static void Connection() {

    final String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlite:D:\\Users\\IdeaProject\\modus\\src\\model\\modus.db";

    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
        System.out.println("Connected");
        //while(returnStatement.next()) {
        //System.out.println("rs.getString");
        //}

        } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The error I get is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:D:\\Users\\Duncan Skilton\\IdeaProject\\modus\\src\\model\\modus.db
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
at controller.databaseConnect.Connection(databaseConnect.java:16)
at sample.Main.main(Main.java:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
```

Process finished with exit code -1

Anything you can suggest will be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `Driver` for your dbms. Add this to your pom.xml when using maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
  <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>3.25.2</version>
</dependency>
```

or this

```
implementation 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.25.2'
```

to your build.gradle when using gradle.

P.S.:I don't think url is correct either. You don't pass the url to file on your drive, find some examples of urls for sqlite on the internet.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! I will have a look at adding Gradle to my project :) I'll report back